# Grabbing XML or Plist file and displaying it with a URL

Tags: php, xml

I am creating an app where it installs third-party apps that are not on the appstore using Plists.

What I am wanting to do is have an existing plist on the internet.
(ex. https://tutuapp.com/va/3088464.plist)

it shows:

[The XML or PLIST file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aswLu.png)

And display it on my domain with one link.

---

I'm looking for somthing like this:

Link - `mydomain.com/download.php?url=https://tutuapp.com/va/3088464.plist`
then it would show the plist file.

Comment: Have you tried this? `echo file_get_contents('https://tutuapp.com/va/3088464.plist');`

Comment: It worked! ur amazing!

Comment: @DanielO. The plist wont install anymore :(

Comment: Maybe they are blocking too many requests.